# Can a semicategory not have a set as objects?

Tags: category-theory

I see the definition of a semicategory as a set of objects and for any two objects a set of morphisms that are associative(no identity morphism required). My question is if the objects need to be a set, and if it is not allowed to have a class as objects(something larger than a set, like the class of all partial functions). I'm not asking if the morphisms can be a class, only the objects. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't, same as a category.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan I cannot understand you. Is it allowed?

Comment: Yes, it's fine, same as a category. You phrased the question differently in the body.